# redis sentinel not promoting +sdown to +odown

Tags: redis

I setup a cluster of 3 redis-sentinel (3.2.6-1) on three instance of redis-server (3.2.6-1).

I checked the firewall for the 6379 and 26379 TCP port and it's all good.

The configuration for my redis-sentinel is something like that:

```
port 26379
dir "/tmp"
sentinel myid 0559ec26112bebce70bbfa5849f77338453315b
sentinel monitor rback 10.3.0.43 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds rback 5000
sentinel failover-timeout rback 10000
daemonize yes
pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis-sentinel.pid"
loglevel notice
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis-sentinel.log"
```

When I start the redis-server and redis-sentinel instances, I can query on the port 26379 port `sentinel master rback` and see the options:

```
9) "flags"
10) "master"
...
31) "num-slaves"
32) "2"
33) "num-other-sentinels"
34) "2"
35) "quorum"
36) "2"
```

In the logs of the redis-sentinel, I see this:

```
26851:X 12 Jun 15:22:35.092 * +sentinel sentinel 4b22b6ff1b983432028f8cdb0db75cd553bec4b3 XXXXX 26379 @ redis-back XXXXX 6379
26851:X 12 Jun 15:22:40.105 * +sentinel sentinel 8fc263bf82226364917478541c13f2c7f5b746e6 XXXXX 26379 @ redis-back XXXXX 6379
26851:X 12 Jun 15:22:40.168 # +sdown sentinel 4b22b6ff1b983432028f8cdb0db75cd553bec4b3 XXXXX 26379 @ redis-back XXXXX 6379
26851:X 12 Jun 15:22:45.120 # +sdown sentinel 8fc263bf82226364917478541c13f2c7f5b746e6 XXXXX 26379 @ redis-back XXXXX 6379
```

And if I run the sleep command or crash the master redis, I see each sentinel logging a `+sdown` command, but never promote it to `+odown` and promoting a new master.

How can I debug this?

Thanks

Add Information:

I run a tcpdump and analyse the traffic with wireshark, and found out that the sentinel is connecting to the other sentinel and try to communicate with it, but receive a "DENIED Redis is running in protected mode...". Even though the redis-servers are not running in protected mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the communication between the sentinel.

Redis adds with 3.2 version a "protected-mode" configuration flag on the sentinel.conf too.

The sentinel will receive an error message "Denied Redis is running in protected mode..." if the sentinel doesn't have the flag.

I found this information here:
https://newbiedba.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/redis-3-2-sentinel-with-protected-mode/